# Select last date for each month from a dates collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby on Rails I have a collection of data which needs to be filtered to get the most recently created ones of each month. What is the **best optimized** way to do this?

e.g

```
["2012-1-2","2012-1-18", "2012-1-5", "2012-2-15","2012-2-23","2012-2-4"]
```

result should be

```
["2012-1-18, "2012-2-23", ..]
```

Comment: Where is your version of it?

Comment: What is the relation between the nested arrays in the input and the flat array in the result? It is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. Lets just assume its not a nested array but just an array with dates.

Comment: You say that you're using Rails, so I have to ask, are you getting these out of a database?

Comment: Yes the data is getting out of a database. When doing it in the application level we found its too be slow. Now trying to move for a db level complex query to do the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def last_in_month(dates)
  dates = dates.map {|date_string| Date.parse(date_string)}
  grouped_by_month = dates.group_by {|date| date.month}
  grouped_by_month.map do |month, dates_in_month|
    dates_in_month.max_by {|d| d.day}
  end
end

last_in_month(your_nested_arrays.flatten)
```

Returns dates objects.

Transform to strings again :)

```
last_in_month(your_nested_arrays.flatten).map {|d| d.to_s(:db)}
```

Comment: Why do `Date.new(*date_string.split("-").map {|d| d.to_i})` when you can just do `Date.parse(date_string)`?

Comment: How is `Date.parse` magic? As long as you know what it does and how it does it, it cannot be magic. If you don't know, then learn instead of banishing it outright.

Comment: This will group the same months of different years as a single group. It is not clear whether the OP intended this, but I suppose not.

Comment: Ok, let it be. I don't mind.) Are you fan of .parse? I can be fan of .strptime or any other. What does it really change if it does what it has to?

Comment: sawa, what if he looking for a last of the month over the all years ?)

Answer (score 1):

```
["2012-1-2","2012-1-18", "2012-1-5", "2012-2-15","2012-2-23","2012-2-4"]
.group_by{|s| s[/\d+-\d+/]}
.values
.map{|a| a.max_by{|s| s[/\d+\z/].to_i}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
my_date = ["2012-1-2","2012-1-18", "2012-1-5", "2012-2-15","2012-2-23","2012-2-4"]
my_date.sort_by{|date| month,day,year=date.split("-");[year,month,day]}
```

But if these dates are coming out of a database table, maybe you could consider sorting it there. That would be a bit faster (especially if there are many records).

Answer (score 0):

```
["2012-1-2","2012-1-18", "2012-1-5", "2012-2-15","2012-2-23","2012-2-4"].map { |d| Date.parse(p) }.sort.group_by { |d| [d.month, d.year].join('/') }.map { |k,v| v.last.strftime("%Y-%-m-%-d") }
```